# Wrong layout positioning in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

My EditText and ImageButton not appear because of wrong positioning. Fragment successfully show up.

Here is my layout view code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e1e1e1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/msgListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#91f1f1f1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxHeight="80dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:text="d" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My full source code is here https://github.com/IntellijSys/AndroidChat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it using my solution.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#e1e1e1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/msgListView"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:text="+@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:background="#91f1f1f1"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="80dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]hey u can use this one

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_messages"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/msgListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_message"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/send"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_send"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

you can use your listView at the place of RecycleView

Comment: since when I need to RecyclerView? all ids already changed up.

Comment: u can set up Ids according to you or u can also use your ListView at the place of RecyclerView

Comment: implement this layout to your code and change ids according to you.

Comment: btw i need to stick with ListView. Your output is not in runtime mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144556/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-tiwari-and-mohammad-nurdin).

Answer (score 0):

Change Position of Listview like your linear layout is behind listview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">



<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:background="#91f1f1f1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.72"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxHeight="80dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:text="d" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/msgListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Hello World" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still same, no changes

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in chat_layout.xml ,Your EditText and ImageButton is hiding because of the AppBarLayout .
You have used `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in ViewPager ,this is why your Bottom part if ChatFragment is not visible for first time,try to drag your tablayout upside .

Comment: so what is the value?